# How to get the percentage of file downloaded IOS

Tags: ios

Hi Does any one how to calculate the percentage of file downloaded when downloading it from a URL using NSUrl. Please help.

Thanks a Lot 
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to get the expected content length in your NSURLConnection's delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];
        downloadedContentLength = 0;
...
}
```

then track the length of the portion you already have in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    downloadedContentLength += [data length];
    int percentage = ((double)downloadedContentLength/contentLength)*100
```

Comment: 'expectedContentLength' getting -1